# Why does sys.exit(4294967295) set %ERRORLEVEL% to -1?

Tags: python, c, windows, cmd, error-code

Stumbled upon this when messing around with a batch script that invokes a Python script.

In the Python script, I was calling `sys.exit(-1)` which sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to 4294967295. After reading that Windows uses 32-bit unsigned integers, I changed it to `sys.exit(4294967295)`, but now the `%ERRORLEVEL%` is -1.

Why does it do the inverse? `sys.exit(-1)` makes sense because its (2^32) -1 and stored with the wrap around, but why does using the maximum value of a 32-bit unsigned integer get converted to -1? Is it something in the C underneath?

Comment: From the [documentation of `sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html): *Most systems require it to be in the range 0–127, and produce undefined results otherwise*

Comment: @EugeneSh. But the Windows documentation handles the range of 0-[(2^32)-1]. So there must be something in the C implementation.

Comment: @ErykSun Okay so `sys.exit` uses the Windows API which has it as `unsigned int`, hence something like `Popen.returncode` would be 4294967295. That value (in memory, so therefore bits) are passed to the NT API as a `long int` and therefore interpreted as a two's-complement signed integer? Wow. Any chance you know where the two APIs have that documented?

Comment: @ErykSun According to the question, `%ERRORLEVEL%` can be either -1 or 4294967295. That's not consistent with CMD simply treating it as a 32-bit signed integer. And aren't the values of environment variables strings? Though at some point the integer status value has to be converted to a string.

Comment: @pstatix Can you confirm that you typed `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` in CMD and it printed `4294967295`? I haven't been able to reproduce that (without setting `ERRORLEVEL` explicitly).

Comment: Note that Python's `sys.exit(status)` -- and `raise SystemExit(status)` beneath that -- handles the exit status as a signed Python integer, and any non-negative value above 2147483647 or any negative value below -2147483648 causes the conversion to a C `long int` to fail and sets the exit status to -1.

Comment: @ErykSun: So there's some magic in the handling of `%ERRORLEVEL%`? That makes sense. (Though I note that `set ERRORLEVEL=-foo` works in CMD. Presumably that's a bad thing to do.)

Comment: @ErykSun: You might consider posting an answer. (I'm still curious how the OP managed to see `%ERRORLEVEL%` with a value of `4294967295`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I can only guess the OP had `errorlevel` actually `set` as an actual variable somehow. The automatic `errorlevel` is always displayed as a signed int. For example running either `call cmd /c exit /b -1` or `call cmd /c exit /b 4294967295` at a cmd prompt has the following `echo %errorlevel%` display `-1`.

Comment: The recommendation for MS-DOS and Windows applications is exiting with a value in range 0 to 32767. That are really enough possible exit codes for all applications. Then it does not matter if the calling process interprets the exit value as 16-bit signed integer or as 16-bit unsigned integer (16-bit applications) or as signed 32-bit integer or as 32-bit unsigned integer (32-bit applications and most 64-bit applications) or as 64-bit signed integer or 64-bit unsigned integer. 16-bit applications are not supported anymore on Windows x64, but they were supported in the past using `ntvdm.exe`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I may have misread which "print" debugging out that value. When using Pythons `Popen`, the `returncode` value from another script that calls `sys.exit(-1)` is set to `4294967295`. According to @ErykSun, this value in the Python API sends `-1` to `uint 32` but then its passed to CMD as an `int 32` resulting in `%ERRORLEVEL%` showing `-1`. The real culprit I had was the Python script in the middle, that was checking the `returncode` of a `sys.exit(-1)`; wasn't catching it since its `4294967295`.

Comment: @Mofi Is that range documented anywhere?

Comment: @ErykSun I'm pushing my way through the Python C source, and I see where in the [sysmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/sysmodule.c#L815)  raises `SystemExit` but I don't see where that exception eventually calls the Windows API. Do you know where that takes place? Also, what debugger do you use for CMD to dive into its source code?

Comment: @pstatix The range is not documented anywhere. I read various __recommendations__ for exit values of applications for various platforms, but I have not read anywhere a real specification. There is only defined which variants of function __main__ can be used depending on used compiler/library/interpreter with return type __int__ or __unsigned int__, but there is no general specification for Windows as far as I know. __int__ is defined as capable of containing at least the range −32,767 to +32,767 in the C and C++ standards (since C99 when I remember right).

Comment: @pstatix On Linux it is safe to use only the value rage 0 to 127 for application specific return codes to parent process as various system functions of Linux kernel interpret higher values already with special meanings as documented for [exit](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), [wait](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) and others. Linux signals like `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` should result in exiting the application with the signal value + 128 resulting in "user" exit range limited to 0 to 127.

Comment: @Mofi, you're describing the shell behavior, such as bash. Linux doesn't interpret the bits above the first byte from the value returned by `main` or `exit`; it masks them out. Given the wait status `ws` returned by `wait` or `waitpid`, if the process exited then `WIFEXITED(ws)` is true and `WEXITSTATUS(ws)` is the 8-bit exit status. If the process was terminated by a signal, then `WIFSIGNALED(ws)` is true and the signal number is `WTERMSIG(ws)`. On some POSIX systems, but not Linux, the `waitid` system call returns the unmasked 32-bit exit status as the `si_status` field of the result.

Comment: @ErykSun Interesting. Sidebar, how do `pythonrun.c` and `ceval.c` relate? I thought `ceval.c` was the main file for the interpreter.

Comment: Python starts with `Py_Main` in Modules/main.c. Initialization is implemented by several C files such as Python/pylifecycle.c, Python/preconfig.c and Python/initconfig.c, and Modules/getpath.c (or PC/getpathp.c). Eventually it gets to a run function such as `PyRun_FileExFlags` in Python/pythonrun.c. The file is parsed and compiled via `PyParser_ASTFromFileObject` and `PyAST_CompileObject`. With a code object in hand, it calls `PyEval_EvalCode` in Python/ceval.c, which creates a frame object to evaluate the code, and finally it's executed in `PyEval_EvalFrame`, the loop that executes bytecode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative integer values can be represented using a radix complement. Thus the same underlying four-byte value 0xFFFFFFFF may represent an unsigned 32-bit value 4294967295 or a signed 32-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) value -1. It's just a matter of how the bytes are interpreted in context, which includes the use of signed vs unsigned instructions such as, for example in the x86 ISA, `JG` (jump if greater -- signed) versus `JA` (jump if above -- unsigned).

When CMD waits for a process to exit, it gets the exit status via [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) and saves it as the 32-bit signed integer `cmd!LastRetCode`. (*module_name!symbol_name* is how a debugger such as windbg or cdb references a global symbol name in a loaded module.) CMD interprets the exit status as a signed integer even though, at the API level, Windows returns a `DWORD`, which is a C typedef for `unsigned long`.

Normally the process exit status in Windows is an unsigned 16-bit value in the range 0-65535. Often it's pass-fail, i.e. either [`EXIT_SUCCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/exit-success-exit-failure?view=vs-2019) (0) or `EXIT_FAILURE` (1). However, if a Windows program terminates abnormally, such as an unhandled exception, the status code will typically be an `NTSTATUS` value, which is a 32-bit signed integer, which represents warnings and failures as negative values. For example, an access violation is `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` (0xC0000005 or -1073741819).

A batch script might require special handling for when a program terminates abnormally. The last exit status can be tested with the `errorlevel <number>` expression, which is true if the last exit status is equal to or greater than the specified number. For example:

```
C:\>cmd /c exit -1073741819
C:\>if errorlevel 0 (echo normal exit) else (echo abnormal exit)
abnormal exit
```

CMD itself has special handling to print "^C" for `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` (0xC000013A or -1073741510), the exit status that indicates an unhandled console control event, which includes unhandled Ctrl+C (cancel) and Ctrl+Break. For example:

```
C:\>cmd /c exit -1073741510
^C
```

In addition to the `errorlevel` check, CMD has a builtin `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable. Builtin environment variables aren't actually stored in the process environment block. They're supplied as default values. In a debugger you can observe that CMD calls `cmd!GetEnvVar` to get the value of an environment variable. This function first tries WinAPI `GetEnvironmentVariableW`, which either returns a real process environment variable (e.g. `PATH`) or one of the OS builtin variables (e.g. `__APPDIR__`, `__CD__`). If `GetEnvironmentVariableW` fails to find "ERRORLEVEL", `GetEnvVar` defaults to the builtin value, which is the `LastRetCode` value converted to a string via `StringCchPrintfW`, with the format string `"%d"` (i.e. signed decimal integer). For example:

```
C:\>cmd /c exit -1
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
-1

C:\>set errorlevel=foo
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
foo
```

CMD also sets the last exit status as `%=ExitCode%` (conventionally hidden because the name starts with "="), which is the exit status as an unsigned 32-bit value, formatted as a zero-padded hexadecimal number. If the exit status is a printable ASCII ordinal in the range 32-126, CMD also sets `%=ExitCodeAscii%`. For whatever reason, CMD stores these as real environment variables that get inherited by a child process. For example, for an exit status of 65 (i.e. 0x41, i.e. the ASCII ordinal of "A"):

```
C:\>cmd /c exit 65

C:\>python -q
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.GetEnvironmentVariable('=ExitCode')
'00000041'
>>> win32api.GetEnvironmentVariable('=ExitCodeAscii')
'A'
```

---

Regarding `sys.exit(4294967295)` in Python, note that `sys.exit(status)` -- and `raise SystemExit(status)` beneath that -- handles the exit status as a signed Python integer that gets converted to a C `long int` in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647. Using a value outside of this range causes the conversion to fail and sets the exit status to -1. See [`_Py_HandleSystemExit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/90eff4ed4445a0fa9d8cdf74c0f86c50ed510dad/Python/pythonrun.c#L620) in the source code published on GitHub. It happens that 4294967295 (0xFFFFFFFF) is the two's complement representation of -1, but you'll get the same result for any other unsupported value. For example:

```
C:\>python -c "raise SystemExit(9876543210)"
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
-1
```

The normal exit status is 0 for success and 1 for failure, including when an error message is printed to stderr:

```
C:\>python -c "raise SystemExit"
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0

C:\>python -c "raise SystemExit('whoops-a-daisy...')"
whoops-a-daisy...
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1
```